# How to read video from URL in FileVideoStream in imutils?

Tags: python

I have a Python program with a video file reader scenario. To do this, I use the FileVideoStream API from the library imutils.video as follows

```
from imutils.video import FileVideoStream
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2

vs = FileVideoStream('~/Downloads/capture.webm').start()
time.sleep(1.0)

while True:
    if not vs.more():
        print("vs", vs.more())
        vs.stop()
        break
    print("vs", vs.more())
    frame = vs.read()
```

**The problem is the location "~/Downloads/capture.webm" is not recognized by the FileVideoStream function even the video file is exists in the mentioned directory.**

```
ERROR: OpenCV: Couldn't read video stream from file "~/Downloads/capture.webm"
```

But when I save the video in the same python project directory and call as "capture.webm" it works!

**And also the function doesn't recognize videos from a URL.**

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Completion for `~` inside path `~/Downloads/capture.webm` is done by `bash/sh/etc.`. If you are using python you have to use full path `/home/username/Downloads/capture.webm`.

You can also use `os.environ.get('USER')` to get current USER name and insert it inside full path. For example

```py
'/home/%s/Downloads/capture.webm' % os.environ.get('USER')
```